# Overriding mvvmcross View locator

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have  been refactoring my working solution, into using multiple assemblies as reusable modules.    It has the  following assemblies

**App.Framework** - common project across all aspects of the solution, 
**App.Core -** mvvmcross core, 
**App.StartupModule** - part of modules for different parts of the app , for reusablity in other projects, It contains its own repos, services and viewmodels.
**App.Windows**,
**App.Android**

I have managed to solve the viewodellocator and have the type from the module assemnly   and using the following to start the app where the startupView is the default view for that particular module.

```
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("RegisterAppStart", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .MakeGenericMethod(startupView);
        method.Invoke(this, null);
```

So the app runs all the way through core and then into the windowsphone app  and when it tries to find the view associated with logonviewmodel it breaks. the namespace has changed from

```
App.Core.ViewModels.[VIEWMODELNAME] -> App.StartupModule.ViewModels.[VIEWMODELNAME]
```

This is the part of the debug trace where i think it is failing

```
    mvx:Diagnostic: 84.00 Error seen during navigation request to LogonViewModel - error KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for App.StartupModule.ViewModels.LogonViewModel
       at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewsContainer.GetViewType(Type viewModelType)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsCommon.Views.MvxWindowsViewPresenter.Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
```

The view is located in the namespace

```
App.WindowsPhone.Views
```

So i guess my questions are 
1. is there an easy way to tell the viewdispatcher/viewlocator to look in the project for view of type [VIEWMODELNAME] 
2. is it better to override the mappings? and how would one go about doing this? 
3. Any other suggestions of what to override to fix this?
4. From what ive seen this will require an implementation on each platform of something, im guessing there is no generic way to handle this for all platforms?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after many trial error attempts at many different things , i found the solution to the problem. it is not particularly elegant and needs some refactor but what you need to do. 
1. in the setup of your UI project , you need to add the **Viewmodel** assemblies and then the world is good again and the solution continues to run, however it needs to happen on each platform. and not the view assemblies

```
    protected override System.Reflection.Assembly[] GetViewModelAssemblies()
    {
      //  return base.GetViewModelAssemblies();

        var result = base.GetViewModelAssemblies();
        var assemblyList = result.ToList();

        var assemblyType = typeof(SBG.NBOL.StartupModule.ViewModels.LogonViewModel);
        assemblyList.Add(assemblyType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        return assemblyList.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The view resolution does not take the namespace in which the views are declared into consideration. So it doesn't matter in what namespace your view is defined.

By convention the mapping works on base of type name. So if you do a `ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>()` it will try to find a view named FirstView. It will try to find the view in the assembly of the native iOS or Android app.

If you've defined the view in a different assembly, you can override the `AndroidViewAssemblies` property of your platform specific `Setup` class.

Comment: Thats what i thought would happen, however after making my changes it can no longer find the view in my ui project , which was working fine before? so not sure whats happened then :/

Comment: I shuold probably add that i have overridden the navigation and am using this
    public void Navigate(Type viewModelType, object parameters)
        {
            ShowViewModel(viewModelType, parameters);
        }

Comment: Did you define the View in a different assembly than the native iOS, Windows or Android project?

Comment: Nope view remains in the same assembly as before

Comment: And you're also sure that your view derives from any of the `IMvxView` derivative classes? eg. `MvxActivity`, `MvxViewController` or something similar?

Comment: Yes my views derive from mvx views. the entire system was fully functional when viewmodel was in teh core project, i moved it to another project and adjusted the viewmodellocator so it knows where to get it , and now the view cannot be found